# INSERT INTO no funciona y el codigo no da error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Intento insertar datos a la base, mysql y no lo hace me da el error del else y ningún error de php o algo, hace 3 días que estoy tratando de buscar como hacerlo y nada, el código esta bien, pero me tira el error y la base de datos no recibe nada, y phpMyAdmin me da error en el INSERT de ejemplo de todas las bases de datos que tengo, pero las otras bases con código similar funcionan correctamente y la de mi base no hay forma, quería terminar este proyecto hoy, y no va a poder ser parece, este error me dejo out, es mas, tengo en el mismo proyecto la sección usuarios con el código similar y si me agrega usuarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
<?php 
require_once('conexion.php');
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$productos = $_POST['productos'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = "INSERT INTO proveedores (nombre,productos,telefono,email) values('$nombre','$productos','$telefono','$email')";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
if($resultado){
 header('Location: /TiemposdeCambios/bootstrap/proveedores.php');
} else{echo "errores";}
 
 ?>
```

```html
<?php  
include ('php/conexion.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']))
    {
    echo "session exitosa";
    } else
        {
        header('Location: login.php');
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Agregar Usuario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<?php  
include("php/header.php");
?>
<div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Agregar Usuario</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="php/guardar_proveedor.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-doc-text"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="productos" placeholder="Productos de este proveedor">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-phone-3"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-mail-1"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="proveedores.php">Cancelar</a>
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Agregar">
                        </div>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En la consulta de phpmyadmin que quiere decir tu [value - 1];?

Comment: Además teléfono es de tipo Int y en la consulta de php lo metes como char o varchar, quítale las comillas simples al value de teléfono y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda! ya funciona, aunque como tu lo dices tampoco me funciono y tiro el error, cambie el tipo de dato INT de telefono a varchar y anda bien jeje

Comment: y no se que es ese VALUE-1 me dejo helado!! aun sigue apareciendo aunque el codigo funcione.-

Comment: De cuanto era el valor que ingresabas? recuerda que int solo admite hasta 11 caracteres, de todas formas siempre se recomienda poner un número telefónico como varchar o char en vez de númerico.

Comment: Era de 10 caracteres !! 3571414073 >.<, eso si lo sabía jeje pero no se porque no lo aceptaba!! habia visto un tutorial en el que usaban INT para telefonos por eso use ese tipo de dato!!

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en la consulta SQL. 
Recuerda el teléfono en tu base de datos es de tipo `int`, por tanto deberías  eliminar las comillas `'$telefono'`, de modo que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO proveedores (nombre,productos,telefono,email) values('$nombre','$productos',$telefono,'$email')";
```

espero te funcione

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, eh cambiado el tipo de dato a VARCHAR para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

como [dice oscar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114471/83), tienes que chequear los tipos de datos y precisar que lo que estas enviando desde php esta acorde con lo q recibe el mysql para gestionar el insert correctamente, te aconsejo lo siguiente:

corre la consulta primero en mysql con un juego cualquiera y desde php creo q debes de hacerla de esta manera

```
$query = "INSERT INTO proveedores (nombre,productos,telefono,email) values('".$nombre."','".$productos."',".$telefono.",'".$email."')";
```

los puntos es para q puedas concatenar los valores de las variables con la cadena, espero q t sirva

Comment: Si asi esi, muchas gracias, ya eh cambiado el tipo de dato de telefono a VARCHAR y anda de maravilla :D